# Whats the best way to send QStrings in a function call?

Tags: string, qt, pointers, pass-by-reference

I would like to know what is the most efficient and practical way of sending a Qstring as a parameter to a function, in QT more specifically.  I want to use a reference. The problem is I also want to instantiate that string in the function itself like so for example:

this is the function prototype:

```
void myFunction(QString & theMsg);
```

this is the function call:

```
myFunction(tr("Hello StringWorld"));
```

now the `function tr()` returns a QString but it doesn't work with a reference(I can see why).

I have to do this:

```
QString theQstr("Hello StringWorld"); 
myFunction(theQstr);
```

Is there a simpler way to do this while still using references or could I just change the function parameter to use a QString and it would still be efficient?

Comment: How about this: myFunction(QString("Hello StringWorld"));

Comment: That generated a compile message. I think it is because this only generates a return value without anything concrete to reference to.

Comment: This link could help: [Right_way_to_pass_QString_to_methods](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Right_way_to_pass_QString_to_methods)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c) The fact that this question is about `QString` changes nothing about the basic rules of the thumb.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

QString uses COW (Copy On Write) behind the scenes, so the actual string isn't copied even if you use a signature like this:

> void myFunction(QString theMsg)

(until you modify it that is).

If you absolutely want a reference I would use a const& unless you plan to modify the input argument.

> void myFunction(QString const& theMsg)

Comment: No thats great, thx! this is what I wanted to know.  So it actually does the same thing as an NSString in Objective-C  on a mac.

Comment: If you look in the Qt source code, you'll see that Qt itself tends to pass Qt types as const T& to functions.  Even though they use COW, there is still slightly more overhead in copying a class than just passing a reference.

Comment: @Colin Can you elaborate on that overhead? I just looked at the source and a QString is just a wrapper around a pointer. I sizeof()ed a `QString` and a `const QString&` to be sure, and both were 4 bytes. Since a QString is basically a pointer itself (and refs are effectively pointers) why would it be more efficient to pass a pointer to a pointer instead of just passing the pointer itself? Sounds like the const-ref would be slightly less efficient...

Comment: @weberc2 I'm not 100% sure about what goes on under the hood in C++, but even if a QString is just a wrapper around a pointer, it seems like there'd be some steps that would need to be taken to figure that out. For example, I'd expect it would need to check for the existence of a copy constructor. Even if there isn't one, or if the copy constructor is just making a copy of the pointer QString wraps, that's still an extra function call.

Comment: @Colin The C++ compiler validates the existence of a copy constructor *at compilation time*; this doesn't happen on the fly (c++ is not a dynamic, interpreted language). Moreover, C++ compilers are very, very good at optimizing away function calls. I did some research, and it looks like the overhead is due to the reference-counting, so basically it amounts to an increment operation (incrementing the ref count), a copy op (copying the wrapped pointer), and a comparison op (is the ref count > 0? Do we need to free the pointee?). So yeah, it's a couple of operations bigger...

Comment: @Colin ... but not worth compromising clarity.

Comment: A copy on write object still has to maintain a pointer to the data and a reference count (atomic increment / decrement) and run through a copy constructor and a destructor. So even if its reasonably efficient it is still more efficient to just pass by reference where you can. It might also make certain inline functions zero-cost if the compiler knows it doesn't have to do anything with the param.

Answer (score 10):

The most efficient and practical way is using a const reference. The QString COW will be slower than pass by reference but faster than a regular copy.

Comment: Why? [more chars to make the comment valid]

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a QString, the call site has to call QString copy ctor then a dtor: both implies an atomic reference counting operation (not neglectable), and some more generated assembly code. Hence slower and bigger code (I don't mention here the less common std::move scenario).

On the other hand, when you pass a const QString&, on the called site, there is a double indirection to access the characters: a pointer to a pointer. Hence this is slower than passing a QString, especially if the QString parameter is much used.

I would recommend to always pass a const QString&, and if you need maximum speed on the called side, make a QString copy there, and access this local copy to avoid a double-indirection (faster, less generated code).